# real analysis The e number

Tags: real-analysis

How can show
 $$\frac{{{{\left( {1 + \frac{1}{n}} \right)}^{{n^2}}}}}{{{{\left( {1 + \frac{1}{{n + 1}}} \right)}^{{{(n + 1)}^2}}}}} < \frac{1}{{{{\left( {1 + \frac{1}{n}} \right)}^n}}}$$

Comment: This perhaps works, take the ln on both sides and write fractions inside with a common denominator. Keep splitting the ln terms. Work out (n+1)² and distribute over ln terms. It clears a lot up

Comment: Multiply both sides by the inverse of the RHS and note the difference in the remaining exponents on the LHS.

Comment: Do you already know that $\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)^k$ is increasing? Your inequality is an immediate consequence.

Answer (score 3):

Using [Bernoulli's Inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality),
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\left(1+\frac1{n+1}\right)^{(n+1)^2}}{\left(1+\frac1n\right)^{n^2}}
&=\left(\frac{n(n+2)}{(n+1)^2}\right)^{(n+1)^2}\left(1+\frac1n\right)^{2n+1}\\
&=\left(1-\frac1{(n+1)^2}\right)^{(n+1)^2}\left(1+\frac1n\right)^{n+1}\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n\\
&\ge\left(1-\frac1{n+1}\right)^{n +1}\left(1+\frac1n\right)^{n+1}\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n\\
&=\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n
\end{align}
$$

---

**Second approach:**
Using [this result](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/306245)
$$
\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n\le\left(1+\frac1{n+1}\right)^{n+1}
$$
Raise both sides to the $n+1^\text{st}$ power
$$
\left(1+\frac1n\right)^{n(n+1)}\le\left(1+\frac1{n+1}\right)^{(n+1)^2}
$$
Divide both sides by $\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n\left(1+\frac1{n+1}\right)^{(n+1)^2}$
$$
\frac{\left(1+\frac1n\right)^{n^2}}{\left(1+\frac1{n+1}\right)^{(n+1)^2}}\le\frac1{\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n}
$$