# Decreasing sequence proof

Tags: sequences-and-series

I would like to know if this proof is valid or whether there is a more elegant solution.
$$a_n=(1+\frac{1}{n})^{n+1}$$
I want to prove that it is decreasing.
$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{n+2}{n}(1-\frac{1}{(n+1)^2})^{n+2}$$
Using bernoulli inequality
$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\leq e^{-\frac{n+2}{(n+1)^2}}$$
$e$ exponent is $<0 $ and we know that $e^x<1$ with $x<0$ so
$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}<1$$

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/306178).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Given $y_n=(1+\frac{1}{n})^{n+1},n \in \mathbb{N},n \geq 1$ Show that $\lbrace y_n \rbrace$ is a decrasing sequence](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/306178/given-y-n-1-frac1nn1-n-in-mathbbn-n-geq-1-show-that-lbrace-y)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my working out of that proof.

I am not sure what you have as Bernoulli inequality, but I take it as 
$$1+na \leq (1+a)^n$$

I show $1 \leq \frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}$.
Now,
$$
\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}=\frac{
\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n+1}}{\left(1+\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^{n+2}}
=\left( \frac{(n+1)^2}{n(n+2)} \right)^{n+2} \left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right).
$$
Now by the Bernoulli inequality, (with $a=\frac{1}{n^2+2n}$)
$$\frac{n+1}{n} \leq \left( \frac{(n+1)^2}{n(n+2)} \right)^{n+2}$$

Comment: This is similar to [my answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/306245) for [the older question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/306178).

Comment: I was refering to the related type http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality