# Prove that the sequence $b_n=\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n+1}$ is decreasing

Tags: sequences-and-series

Prove that the sequence
$$b_n=\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n+1}$$
Is decreasing.

I have calculated $b_n/b_{n-1}$ but it is obtain:
$$\left(1-\frac{1}{n^2}\right)^n \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n$$
But I can't go on.

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$y=\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^{x+1}$$

$$\ln y=({x+1})\cdot\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)$$

$$y'\frac{1}{y}=\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)+(x+1)\cdot \frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{x}}\cdot\left(-\frac{1}{x^2}\right)$$

$$y'=\left(\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)-\frac{1}{x}\right)\cdot\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^{x+1}$$

$$\Rightarrow y'<0$$

Hence $y$ is decreasing

Answer (score 0):

Hint: using the tools of differential calculus, study the function
$$x\longmapsto \left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^{x+1}$$
for $x>0$.

Comment: This seems to be a restatement of the question. Perhaps you could elaborate.

Comment: @robjohn, study using the tools of differential calculus.

Comment: This should be in your answer, not in a comment. However, this can be shown using pre-calculus tools such as [Bernoulli's Inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality). See the answers to the [earlier question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/306178/given-y-n-1-frac1nn1-n-in-mathbbn-n-geq-1-show-that-lbrace-y).

Comment: See [Mhenni Benghorbal's answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/306251) to the [earlier question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/306178/given-y-n-1-frac1nn1-n-in-mathbbn-n-geq-1-show-that-lbrace-y).

Comment: @robjohn, and the answer of Digital Brain, and... Definitely a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $f(x) = (x+1)\ln (x+1) - (x+1)\ln x$ on $x \geq 1$, we have:

$f'(x) = \ln\left(1 + \dfrac{1}{x}\right) - \dfrac{1}{x} < 0$ because it is true that $e^r \geq 1 + r$, and apply this for $r = \dfrac{1}{x} > 0$. From this the answer follows.

Answer (score 0):

Since the inequality holds for any positive numbers:$$\sqrt[n]{{a_1}{a_2}\cdots {a_n}}\ge \frac{n}{a_1^{-1}a_2^{-1}\cdots a_n^{-1}},$$we have:$$\sqrt[n+2]{\underbrace{\frac{n+1}n\frac{n+1}n\cdots \frac{n+1}n}_{n+1\text{ times}}\cdot 1}\ge \frac{n+2}{\frac n{n+1}+\frac n{n+1}+\cdots +\frac n{n+1}+1}.$$Hence,$$\left(1+\frac 1n\right)^{n+1} \ge \left(1+\frac 1{n+1}\right)^{n+2}.$$

Answer (score 0):

My 2¢: consider the function defined apriori for  $x>0$
$$f(x)=\log(1+x)\cdot (\frac{1}{x}+1)= \frac{\log(1+x)\cdot (1+x)}{x}$$

$f$ extends analytically to $(-1, \infty)$, and continuously to $[-1, \infty)$. We have $f(-1)=0$ and $f(0)=1$.

We calculate: $$f'(x)= \frac{x - \log(1+x)}{x^2}$$
so $f'(x)>0$ for $x> -1$, $x \ne 0$ and so $f$ strictly increasing on $(-1, \infty)$. Now consider the decreasing sequence of values $\frac{1}{n}$ for $x$.

Comment: It might be useful to point out that this corresponds to the question by $x=1/n$ and that since $f(x)$ is increasing in $x$, $f(1/n)$ is decreasing in $n$.

Comment: @robjohn: Correct.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you change your goal to prove that $b_n-b_{n+1}>0$?

$b_n-b_{n+1}=(1+1/n)^n-(1+1/n)^n(1+1/n)=(1+1/n)^n(1-1-1/n)=(1+1/n)^n(-1/n)$

Since $n$ is a natural number, $-1/n < 0$. Since $1>0, 1/n>0$, we have $1+1/n>0$. It would be nice if you can use $(1+1/n)^n >0$ directly based on $1+1/n>0$. If not, just do a simple proof by induction.

Then you will have your $b_n-b_{n+1}>0$, i.e., $b_n> b_{n+1}$, meaning that $b_n$ is decreasing.

Comment: Please use MathJax. It makes answers much more readable. Also, notice that this question is a duplicate.

Comment: Your statement that "bn-bn+1>0" seems to say "1>0" which is true, but trivial. I am sure this is not what you meant; I am sure what you meant was $b_n-b_{n+1}\gt0$.

Comment: Now that OC-Sansoo has kindly converted your post to MathJax, it appears that you are mistakenly saying that $b_n=(1+1/n)^n$ and $b_{n+1}=(1+1/n)^{n+1}$. One or both of these is wrong.

Comment: Your worry is valid. Let me redo the calculation

Comment: Your answer supposedly shows that $b_n-b_{n+1}\lt0$ which means $b_n$ is *increasing*. This is not right.