# Prove convergence of $(1-\frac xk)^k$ as $k\to\infty$ using arithmetic-geometric mean

Tags: calculus, limits, convergence-divergence, exponential-function, means

> Define $f(x):=x^{t-1}e^{-x}$. For $k=1,2,\dots$ let
>   $$f_k(x)=\begin{cases}x^{t-1}\left(1-\frac xk\right)^k & 0<x<k\\0&k\le x\le \infty\end{cases}$$
>   Show that $f_k(x)\to f(x)$ and $f_k(x)\le f_{k+1}(x),\forall x>0$.
>
> *Hint*: Use the arithmetic-geometric mean inequality.  You may *not* use the definition of the exponential function as a limit.

I can show the first part without using the arithmetic-geometric mean inequality, but this is probably not the expected solution. I don't see any starting point for using the mean inequality.

How to prove this?

Comment: [This answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/306245) may be of use.

Comment: Which definitions of  the exponential function we may use?