# Derivative: $e^x$.

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

How do you differentiate $e^x$?

I looked on many sites, including similar questions here but most answers seemed circular.

The only known definition of $e$ to be used in this proof is 
$$
e=\lim_{n \to\infty} \left(1+\frac{1}n \right)^n
$$

What I did is:

$$
\begin{align*}
(e^x)' &=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{e^{x+h}-e^x}h \\
&= e^x\lim_{h\to0}\frac{e^{h}-1}h
\end{align*}
$$

But I don't know how to go on, I know  $\lim_{h\to0}\frac{e^{h}-1}h=1$ but I don't know how to prove it, I can't use the $e^x$ taylor expansion as that would imply diferentiating $e^x$.

Edit: I also can't use the derivative of $\ln(x)$.

Comment: Are you allowed to use Newton's binomial theorem? If so then you just have to expand in binomial series $(1 + 1/n)^{hn}$, substract 1 and find that the only term surviving the limiting process is $h/h =1$, from whence the limit follows.

Comment: @RogelioMolina Yes, I'm allowed to use the binomial theorem, could you elaborate on that? I couldn't follow you.

Comment: See [characterizations of the exponential function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characterizations_of_the_exponential_function), especially the paragraph about their equivalence.

Comment: Another point of interest: You've defined $e$ as  a limit. How is $e^h$ defined for all $h\in \mathbb {R}$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We must calculate the limit

$$
\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{e^h -1}{h}
$$
using the definition we have for $e$ we have

$$
\lim_{h \to 0}\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{(1+1/n)^{hn} -1}{h}
$$
we expand using the binomial theorem:

$$
(1+ 1/n)^{hn} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{hn}{k}(1/n)^k = 1 + h + h^2 \cdots
$$
Then the tricky part (this needs to be justified carefully), we exchange the limits to get:

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{1 + h + h^2 \cdots -1}{h} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \lim_{h\to 0}(1 + h\cdots) = \lim_{n \to \infty}1 =1
$$

Comment: I thought the binomial theorem was only applicable if we are raising to an integer power.  As $h$ grows small, $hn$ may no longer be an integer, right?

Comment: The binomial theorem (or a version of it) is valid for all complex powers. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series

Comment: Even if you don't accept the general binomial theorem, for $h$ rational, there will be a **subsequence** of $(1+1/n)^{hn}$ where the exponent is an integer, so provided you accept that the original sequence at least converges, there is no loss of generality in assuming $hn$ is integral.

Comment: I'm having trouble seeing why $$
 \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{hn}{k}(1/n)^k = 1 + h + h^2 \cdots
$$ for the second term I obtain $\frac{h^{2}}{2}-\frac{h}{2n}$

Answer (score 6):

Bernoulli's inequality gives that for any $n\geq 2$ we have:
$$\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n < e < \left(1+\frac{1}{n-1}\right)^n\tag{1} $$
hence $n\left(e^{\frac{1}{n}}-1\right)$ is between:
$$ 1 < n\left(e^{\frac{1}{n}}-1\right) < 1+\frac{1}{n-1}\tag{2}$$
hence, by squeezing:
$$ \lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{e^{\frac{1}{n}}-1}{\frac{1}{n}}=1 \tag{3}$$
that, together with $(2)$, gives:
$$ \lim_{r \to 0}\frac{e^r-1}{r}=1\tag{4}$$
that is enough to grant:
$$ \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{e^{x+h}-e^{x}}{h}=e^x \tag{5} $$
as wanted.

Comment: (+1) I was going to go this way before I saw your answer. I am just too slow in my old age! Bernoulli's Inequality is so very useful.

Comment: I hope you don't mind. I've added an answer to add a bit more detail about how $(1)$ is derived from Bernoulli's Inequality.

Answer (score 6):

This is really a comment on Jack D'Aurizio's answer, but it is too long for a comment. Let me show how Bernoulli's Inequality is used to prove $(1)$ from Jack D'Aurizio's answer.

In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/306245), it is shown, using [Bernoulli's Inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality), that
$$
\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n\tag{1}
$$
is an increasing sequence and that
$$
\left(1+\frac1n\right)^{n+1}\tag{2}
$$
is a decreasing sequence. This means that for all $n$
$$
\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n\le\overbrace{\lim_{k\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1k\right)^k}^{\large e}\le\left(1+\frac1n\right)^{n+1}\tag{3}
$$
Since $(3)$ is true for all $n$, we can substitute $n\mapsto n-1$ in the right-side inequality to get the inequality from Jack's answer:
$$
\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n\le e\le\left(1+\frac1{n-1}\right)^n\tag{4}
$$

Answer (score 3):

\begin{equation*}
 e^x=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\left(1+\frac {x} {n}\right)^n =\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sum_{k=0}^n\binom n k\frac {x^k} {n^k}
=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sum_{k=0}^n\frac {n(n-1)...(n-k+1)} {k!}\frac {x^k} {n^k}\end{equation*}
$$
=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sum_{k=0}^n\frac {n(n-1)...(n-k+1)} {n^k}\frac {x^k} {k!}=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sum_{k=0}^n\frac {n} {n}\frac {n-1}{n}...\frac{n-k+1} {n}\frac {x^k} {k!}$$
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sum_{k=0}^n\frac {1} {1}\left(1-\frac {1}{n}\right)...\left(1-\frac{k-1} {n}\right)\frac {x^k} {k!}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac {x^k} {k!}$$
Hence we have that
$$e^x=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac {x^k} {k!}\implies(e^x)'=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{kx^{k-1}} {k!}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{x^{k-1}} {(k-1)!}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{x^{k}} {k!}$$
It follows that $e^x=(e^x)'$

Answer (score 2):

Define the log function as $\log x=\int_1^x \frac{dt}{t}$.  The derivative is obviously $1/x$.  The exponential function is the inverse of the log function.  So, we may write

$$\begin{align}
x&=\log (e^x)\\
&=\int_1^{e^x} \frac{dt}{t}
\end{align}$$

Taking the derivative of both sides and applying the chain rule reveals

$$\begin{align}
\frac{dx}{dx}&=1\\
&=\frac{d\log(e^x)}{dx}\\
&=\frac{1}{e^x}\frac{de^x}{dx}
\end{align}$$

whereupon solving for $\frac{de^x}{dx}$ shows that

$$\frac{de^x}{dx}=e^x$$

So, the derivative of the exponential function is  itself!

Answer (score -1):

$$e^x=\sum_{n\ge 0} \frac{x^n}{n!}$$
$$\frac{de^x}{dx}=\frac{d}{dx}[1+x+x^2/2!+x^3/3!+\cdots]=0+1+x+x^2/2+\cdots=\sum_{n\ge 0} \frac{x^n}{n!}=e^x$$

This uses a theorem justifying interchanging the derivative with the summation.

Comment: From the original post: *but I don't know how to prove it, I can't use the ex Taylor expansion as that would imply differentiating $e^x$*.

Comment: @GabrielH The Taylor expansion only requires knowing the derivative at a single point, and that can be easily found by approximation with secant lines.

Comment: The OP has likely not even learned that term by term differentiation of an infinite series is allowed ...

Comment: It is the OP's problem for not including enough context.

Comment: Okay, that may be the case. It wasn't me who down voted. I just pointed out that answer is most likely not helpful to the OP.