# An interesting inequality $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{n+k}<\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}, \ n\ge1$

Tags: inequality, harmonic-numbers

Here is one of the beautiful inequalities from Elementary inequalities by *Mitrovic* 
$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{n+k}<\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},$$
which is easy to prove by calculus using that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{n+k}=\log(2)$.

Now, the question is *How would you prove it without calculus*?

Comment: Jack's solution below is very elegant, but one can also get the result with standard methods. From what you have noted we have $\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{n+k} < \log(2)$ and $\log(2) < \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ follows from taking the exponential to get $2 < e^{\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}}$ and now using $e^{x} > 1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{6!}$ with $x=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ is enough to get there (it reduces to showing $13\sqrt{2} > 18 \implies 338>324$ which is true).

Comment: Yeah, it works (in more ways I guess). However, I have to admit I have a weakness for very clever solutions. :-) @Winther

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Cauchy-Schwarz plus creative telescoping and a bit of luck:

> $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{n+k}<\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+k-1}\sqrt{n+k}}\stackrel{CS}{\leq}\sqrt{n\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\frac{1}{n+k-1}-\frac{1}{n+k}\right)}=\color{red}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}.$$

Comment: Good job there! (+1)

Answer (score 8):

(Alternatively) By using **Root-Mean Square-Arithmetic Mean** we get that

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{n+k}<\sqrt{n\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{(n+k)^2}}<\sqrt{n\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{(n+k)(n+k-1)}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}.$$

Answer (score 3):

Using [Bernoulli's Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality), which can be [proven by induction](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/306245), we get that for $x\ge-n$,
$$
\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n\ge1+x
$$
Taking the limit as $n\to\infty$, we get that for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$,
$$
e^x\ge1+x
$$
which implies that for $x\in(0,1)$,
$$
x\le-\log(1-x)
$$
Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{n+k}
&\le\sum_{k=1}^n\log\left(\frac{n+k}{n+k-1}\right)\\
&=\log(2)\\
&\lt\frac{\sqrt2}2
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k = 1}^{n}{1 \over n + k} & = \sum_{k = n + 1}^{2n}{1 \over k} =
\sum_{k = 1}^{2n}{1 \over k} - \sum_{k = 1}^{n}{1 \over k} = H_{2n} - H_{n}\,,
\qquad\pars{~H_{z}: Harmonic\ Number~}
\end{align}

> [Since](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HarmonicNumber.html)
>   $\ds{\pars{~\gamma:\ Euler\!-\!Mascheroni\ Constant~}}$

$$
\ln\pars{m + {1 \over 2}} + \gamma + {1 \over 24\pars{m + 1}^{2}} < H_{m} <
\ln\pars{m + {1 \over 2}} + \gamma + {1 \over 24m^{2}}
$$
\begin{align}
&\mbox{I'll have}\quad\left\{\begin{array}{rcl}
\ds{H_{2n}} & \ds{<} & \ds{\ln\pars{2n + {1 \over 2}} + \gamma + {1 \over 96n^{2}}}
\\[2mm]
\ds{-H_{n}} & \ds{<} &
\ds{-\ln\pars{n + {1 \over 2}} - \gamma - {1 \over 24\pars{n + 1}^{2}}}
\end{array}\right.
\\[5mm] & \implies
\bbx{\left.\sum_{k = 1}^{n}{1 \over n + k}\right\vert_{\ n\ \geq\ 1} < \ln\pars{2 - {1 \over 2n + 1}} -
{\pars{n + 1/3}\pars{n - 1} \over 32n^{2}\pars{n + 1}^{2}} <\
\ln\pars{2} < \color{#f00}{{\root{2} \over 2}}}
\end{align}

> Indeed, $\ds{\ln\pars{2} \approx 0.6931}$ is a "better bound" that $\ds{{\root{2} \over 2} \approx 0.7071}$ !!!.