# Prove that: $\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n+1}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2n}\ge\frac{2}{3}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, inequality, harmonic-numbers

I've got three inequalities:
$\forall n\in\mathbb N:$

$$\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n+1}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2n} \ge\frac{1}{2}$$

$$\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n+1}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2n} \ge\frac{7}{12}$$

$$\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n+1}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2n}\ge\frac{2}{3}$$

From what I know the LHS converges to something about $0.69$ and each one of them requires the same method, but I can't come up with a proper way to solve it.

> Can someone give me a hint?

Comment: You know that you only need to prove one inequality here, and not "three"?

Comment: As in - if $\frac{1}{n}$+$\frac{1}{n+1}$+...$\frac{1}{2n}$ $\geq$$\frac{2}{3}$, then it will also be $\geq \frac{7}{12}$ and $\geq \frac{1}{2}$ as $\frac{2}{3}>\frac{7}{12}>\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: Hello! I just wanted to inform you that I’ve made slight edits to the MathJax in your post. Nothing about it was mathematically wrong, per se, so if you feel that the math looked prettier beforehand, feel free to roll it back—and keep contributing to this awesome site! $\ddot\smile$

Comment: In fact it suffice to prove the last inequality using classical inequalities see below

Comment: It's easy to see that $$s_n={1\over n}+{1\over n+1}+\cdots+{1\over2n}\gt{1\over2n}+{1\over2n}+\cdots+{1\over2n}={n+1\over2n}\gt{1\over2}$$  It's also easy to see that $$s_n-s_{n+1}={1\over n}-{1\over2n+1}-{1\over2n+2}=\left({1\over2n}-{1\over2n+1}\right)+\left({1\over2n}-{1\over2n+2}\right)\gt0$$ so that $s_n$ is a decreasing sequence, and thus $$s_n\gt s_{2n}={1\over2n}+\cdots+{1\over3n}+{1\over3n+1}+\cdots+{1\over4n}\gt{n+1\over3n}+{n\over4n}\gt{1\over3}+{1\over4}={7\over12}$$  However, I don't see any similarly easy way to get $s_n\gt{2\over3}$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde, it seems to me the implicit challenge here is to find separate proofs, of increasing sophistication, for each inequality. See my comment above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: $$\frac{1}{n}\ge\ln(n+1)-\ln(n)$$

Comment: Actually, equality seems impossible.

Comment: @Burde Yes you're right,but it is enough to solve this problem

Comment: telescope effect , and you will end up with $\ln(2n)-\ln(n) = \ln(2) \approx 0.693 > \frac{2}{3}$

Comment: I got exactly to this point but i wonder if there's any way to estimate the value of $\ln (2)$ other than knowing it

Comment: you could easily prove that $\ln(2) > \frac{2}{3}$ even without knowing its value exactly by exponentiation both side to get that $2 > e^{\frac{2}{3}}$ and use the infinite sum of $e^x$ to bound $e^{\frac{2}{3}}$ by $1+\frac{26}{27}$

Comment: Beautiful. Short and to the point.

Comment: If you know that $e = 2.718\ldots$, then we have $e < 2\sqrt2 = 2^{3/2}$. Therefore $e^{2/3} < 2$, so $\frac23 < \ln2$.

Comment: Thank all of You for helping!

Comment: @Ahmad could you explain how you got $\frac{53}{27}$ as upper bound? Using the 3rd-degree Taylor polynomial of $e^x$ we can show that $e^{-2} > \frac{41}{81}$ plus a 4th-order positive term. Thanks!

Comment: $e^{2/3} = \sum \limits_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(2/3)^k}{k!} \leq 1+\frac{2}{3}+\frac{(2/3)^2}{2!} +\frac{(2/3)^2}{3!} + \sum \limits_{k=4}^{\infty} \frac{(2/3)^k}{24}= 1+\frac{80}{81}$ @user334639 , so its bigger than $1+\frac{26}{27}$ but the argument still holds.

Answer (score 1):

We know that $$\color{red}{ \frac{x}{x+1}\le\ln(x+1)\le x~~~\forall ~x>0\tag{1}\label{eq}}$$

taking $x=\frac{1}{n+k}~~0\le k\le n$ this lead to $$\ln\left(\frac{1}{n+k}+1\right)\le\frac{1}{n+k}~~~\forall ~~0\le k\le n $$
that is 
\begin{split}
\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n+1}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2n} &=&\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{1}{n+k} \ge  \sum_{k=0}^{n} \ln\left(\frac{1}{n+k}+1\right)\\&=&\sum_{k=0}^{n} \ln\left(n+k+1\right)-\ln\left(n+k\right)\\ &=&\ln\left(2n+1\right)-\ln\left(n\right)  \\&= &\ln\left( \frac{2n+1}{n}\right) =  \ln\left( 1 +\frac{n+1}{n}\right) \end{split}

Then, Using the left side of $\eqref{eq}$

$$\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n+1}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2n}  \ge  \ln\left( 1 +\frac{n+1}{n}\right)\ge\frac{n+1}{n+2} \ge  \frac{2}{3} $$
Since for all $n\ge 1$ $$\frac{n+1}{n+2} \ge \frac{1+1}{1+2}  = \frac{2}{3}$$

> Because $x\mapsto \frac{x+1}{x+2}$ is an incresing function with derivative $\frac{1}{(x+2)^2}>0. $

Finally observes that
 $$\frac{2}{3}>\frac{7}{12}>\frac{1}{2}$$