# factorial inequality with $(\frac{n}{2})^n$

Tags: inequality, exponentiation, factorial

I came across a problem with proving an equality:

$n! < e(\frac{n}{2})^n$

I tried to simplify the RHS using the limit of $(1+\frac{1}{n})^n$ as $n$ goes to infinity (to use with $sandwich$), but to no avail. I also thought about using induction, but couldn't prove the inductive step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since [$\left(1+\frac1n\right)^{n+1}$ is decreasing](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/306245), we have
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{2^nn!/n^n}{2^{n+1}(n+1)!/(n+1)^{n+1}}
&=\frac12\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n\\
&\ge\frac{en/2}{n+1}
\end{align}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{n!}{n^n}
&\le\frac{n}{e^{n-1}}\\
&\le\frac{e}{2^n}
\end{align}
$$
where the last inequality is valid for $n\ge6$. We can verify $0\le n\lt6$ manually.

Answer (score 2):

Induction works easily. It is true for $n=1$. The induction step goes as follows:

$(n+1)! = (n+1)n! < (n+1)e(\frac{n}{2})^n$ which is less than $e(\frac{n+1}{2})^{n+1}$ if and only if $2n^n < (n+1)^n \iff 2 < (1+\frac{1}{n})^n$ which is true by Binomial Theorem.

Comment: Oh... I didn't think about using the induction assumption right in the beginning... I feel quite foolish now :P

I'll try it now (Writing it formally, because that seems to be the only way I understand what I'm doing)

Thanks!!

Comment: Wait... actually, I'm not sure if I understand... I'm quite new to all these things (Previously I only used function analysis, and not limits and sequences) So could you please explain the steps you made?

Comment: which step do you want me to explain

Comment: no nevermind. I got it