# Prove that $\ln{n} \lt \sqrt{n}$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}^{*}$ without derivative

Tags: inequality, induction, logarithms, radicals

Prove that $\ln{n} \lt \sqrt{n}$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}^{*}$.

I have tried to prove that using induction but I really don't know how to do it.

I know how to solve it by creating a function $f(x) = \sqrt{x}-\ln{x}$ and then making the derivative, and then show that is bigger than 0. But I need it solved without math analysis (without derrivative, maybe with induction).

How can I do this? Thank you very much!

Comment: How is $\ln n$ defined outside of math analysis ?!

Comment: Well try using: $e^{\sqrt{n}} = 1+ \frac{\sqrt{n}}{1!} + \frac{n}{2!} + \cdots $

Comment: Hint: $\ln x = 2 \ln(\sqrt x)$ for $x>0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that 
$$\ln(x) < \log_2(x).$$
now, it suffices to show that
$$\log_2(x) < \sqrt{x} \Leftrightarrow x<2^{\sqrt{x}}$$
substituting $x \mapsto n^2$ we get
$$n^2<2^n,$$
which is easily proven by induction for $n \ge 3$. $n = 1, 2$ are trivial.

**Update:**

As Del pointed out, this answer is wrong. I tried to delete it, but an accepted answer cannot be deleted. It's funny how it is accepted :).

Comment: For $n \neq 3$. That case can be done separately.

Comment: @DanielFischer thanks, I fixed the answer.

Comment: You need $n\le 2^{\sqrt n}$ for every $n$ natural

Comment: Then if I'm not misunderstanding something you should prove the claim for $n$ equal to the square root of a natural number (if you want to prove the original inequality for every natural number)

Answer (score 3):

Check by hand that it's true for $n\le 4$. Then show that
$$\ln (n+1)-\ln(n)\le \sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt n$$
for $n\geq 5$, from which the result follows by induction. This is equivalent to 
$$ \ln\left(1+\frac1n\right)\le \frac{1}{\sqrt n+\sqrt{n+1}}.$$
If you know that
$$ \left(1+\frac1n\right)^n\le e$$
then 
$$\ln\left(1+\frac1n\right)\le \frac1n \le \frac{1}{2\sqrt{n+1}}\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt n+\sqrt{n+1}}$$
because if $n\geq 5$ then $\frac1n \le \frac{1}{2\sqrt{n+1}}$.

Answer (score 0):

While providing an answer to [another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2086600/understanding-the-proof-of-displaystyle-lim-n-to-infty-sqrt-n-frac1n/2086740#2086740) I proved this inequality $$\frac{\ln{n}}{2n}\leq n^{\frac{1}{2n}}-1\leq \frac{n-1}{(2n-1)\sqrt{n}+1}<\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}$$
or 
$$\frac{\ln{n}}{2n}\leq \frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}$$