# Prove, by applying the Binomial Theorem to $(1+a_n)^n$, that $a_n\leq \sqrt{\frac{2}{n-1}}$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, binomial-theorem

Here, $a_n:=n^{\frac{1}{n}}-1$.

My attempt has been to write

\begin{align*}(1+a_n)^n =& \sum_i^n\binom{n}{i}a_n^i\\
&\geq 1+na_n + \frac{n(n-1)a_n^2}{2}.
\end{align*}
I can't see how to proceed from here. I could somehow show that the LHS is less than or equal to $n+na_n+1$, I'd be done, as the result would be implied.

Comment: You just need that $1+a_n = n^{1/n}$. This gives $(1+a_n)^n = n$.

Comment: On RHS, drop the terms $1$, and $na_n$.

Comment: Oh yeah - got it, thanks

Comment: Try to adapt these calculations to your problem https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2086600/understanding-the-proof-of-displaystyle-lim-n-to-infty-sqrt-n-frac1n/2086740#2086740

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question has been solved in the comments, hence I will prove a sharper upper bound for $a_n=n^{1/n}-1$. For any $n\geq 2$ we have $n=\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{k+1}{k}$, hence:

$$ n^{1/n}=\text{GM}\left(1,\tfrac{2}{1},\ldots,\tfrac{n}{n-1}\right)\leq\text{AM}\left(1,\tfrac{2}{1},\ldots,\tfrac{n}{n-1}\right)=1+\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{k} \tag{1}$$
and by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality
$$ H_{n-1}=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{k}\leq\sqrt{(n-1)\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{k^2}}\leq\sqrt{\frac{\pi^2}{6}(n-1)}\tag{2} $$
hence by $(1)$ and $(2)$ we have that
$$ \forall n\geq 2,\qquad a_n=n^{1/n}-1\leq\color{blue}{\sqrt{\frac{\zeta(2)}{n}}}.\tag{3}$$
By studying the function $g(x)=\sqrt{x}\left[\exp\left(\tfrac{\log x}{x}\right)-1\right]$ over $[1,+\infty)$ we have that $(3)$ can be improved up to
$$ \forall n\geq 1,\qquad a_n=n^{1/n}-1 \leq \color{blue}{\sqrt{\frac{29}{34\,n}}}.\tag{4} $$

Comment: Nice - thanks for the extra insight!