# Prove using the epsilon definition that the limit of the sequence, $(f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{R}) \{a_n\}=n^{\frac{1}{n}}$ as $n\to\infty$ is equal to 1

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, cauchy-sequences

Prove using the definition

$\forall \epsilon>0, \exists N\in\mathbb{N}, s.t. \quad \forall n>N,$ we have $\quad \mid a_n-L\mid<\epsilon$

Comment: Almost the same as https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3921019/limit-of-frac1-sqrtn-n/3921069#3921069

Comment: You can bound the sequence, like [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3827774/how-to-use-the-binomial-theorem-to-show-that-n1-n-to-1-as-n-to-infty?noredirect=1&lq=1), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/115822/how-to-show-that-lim-n-to-infty-n-frac1n-1?noredirect=1&lq=1) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2086600/understanding-the-proof-of-displaystyle-lim-n-to-infty-sqrt-n-frac1n/2086740#2086740) and apply the "epsilon definition" to the bounding sequence.