# Limit $\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)^n \right)^{1/x}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Evaluate $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)^n \right)^{1/x}$$

My attempt: I tried to expand the internal series by substituting the consecutive values of n, but the series that appears is not known to me. Kindly help me to solve the problem.

Comment: I'm not optimistic about a closed form for the inner series, seeing as the $x=1$ case is the [Sophomore's dream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophomore%27s_dream) series

Comment: Max value at x = e

Comment: Sorry before (!) x = e. Assuming sophomore constant > 1.

Comment: @mick You mean $e$ is an upper limit to the value? This follows from $n^n >n!$

Comment: @mick: using $(2)$ from my answer, it is easy to see that the max occurs at $n\sim\frac xe$.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Stirling's formula gives you

$$
n^{-n} \sim \frac{\sqrt{2\pi n}}{n!e^n}.
$$
Hence there exists positive constants $c_1$, $c_2$ such that

$$
\frac{c_1}{n!e^n} \leq n^{-n} \leq \frac{c_2}{(n-1)! e^n}.
$$

Plugging these bounds into our sum yields respectively

$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{x}{n}\right)^n &\geq c_1\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!e^n} \\
&=c_1(e^{x/e}-1)
\end{align}
$$
and
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{x}{n}\right)^n &\leq c_2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{(n-1)!e^n} \\
&=c_2\frac{x}{e}e^{x/e}.
\end{align}
$$

Hence

$$\bigl(c_1(e^{x/e}-1)\bigr)^{1/x} \leq \left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{x}{n}\right)^n\right)^{1/x} \leq \left(c_2\frac{x}{e}e^{x/e}\right)^{1/x}.
$$

It is now clear that the limit seeked is $e^{1/e}$.

Comment: Very smart use of Stirling! Normally people use it to replace factorial with other stuff but you did the reverse. +1

Comment: It can be shown that $c_1=c_2=e$ works, for the last inequality, at least.

Comment: Great answer Rob !

Answer (score 7):

In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/306245), it is shown, using [Bernoulli's Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality), that
$$
\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n\le e\le\left(1+\frac1n\right)^{n+1}\tag1
$$
Thus,
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{x}{(n+1)e}\le\frac{x}{n+1}\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^n=\frac{\left(\frac x{n+1}\right)^{n+1}}{\left(\frac xn\right)^n}
=\frac{x}{n}\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^{n+1}\le\frac{x}{ne}\tag2
\end{align}
$$
Therefore, by induction, for $n\ge1$,
$$
\frac{e}{n!}\left(\frac xe\right)^n\le\left(\frac xn\right)^n\le\frac{x}{(n-1)!}\left(\frac xe\right)^{n-1}\tag3
$$
Summing $(3)$, we get
$$
e\left(e^{x/e}-1\right)\le\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac xn\right)^n\le xe^{x/e}\tag4
$$
and raising $(4)$ to the $1/x$ power yields
$$
\left(e\left(1-e^{-x/e}\right)\right)^{1/x}e^{1/e}\le\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac xn\right)^n\right)^{1/x}\le x^{1/x}e^{1/e}\tag5
$$
and by the [Squeeze Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem), we have
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac xn\right)^n\right)^{1/x}=e^{1/e}\tag6
$$

Comment: Well done Rob.  (+1) And happy holidays to you! -Mark

Comment: @MarkViola: Happy Holidays! Stirling's Formula is a powerful tool, but, when possible, I prefer simpler tools, like induction and Bernoulli's Inequality, which can be proven by induction.

Comment: Indeed.  I've used those tools on several posted solutions on MSE.

Comment: I agree. Those bounds on n! are often enough.

Answer (score 1):

Assume for the moment the truth of the following statement $$x\int_{0}^{1} \dfrac{1}{t^{tx}}dt = \sum_{n \geq 1}  \left(\dfrac{x}{n}\right)^n. \label{e:1} \tag{*}$$

Since $\lim_{x \to \infty} x^{1/x} = 1$ the answer is $$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty} \left(\int_{0}^{1} \left(f(t)\right)^x dt\right)^{1/x} $$
where $f(t) = \dfrac{1}{t^{t}}$, assuming the limit exists.

Since $f(t)$  is continuous on $[0,1]$ (defining $0^0 = 1$) and using the well known result, that for a positive continuous function $g$ on $[0,1]$ we have $$\lim_{x \to \infty}\left(\int_{0}^{1} \left(g(t)\right)^x\right)^{1/x} = \sup_{t \in [0,1]} g(t) \label{e:2}\tag{+}$$ it follows that required limit is $ \sup_{t \in [0,1]} f(t)$. It is easy to see that the maximum of $f(t)$ occurs at $1/e$ so the answer is $f(1/e)=e^{1/e}$.

For a proof of $\eqref{e:1}$ we start with the identity 
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty} \exp( -\lambda u) u^{\alpha - 1}du = \dfrac{\Gamma(\alpha)}{\lambda^\alpha}. 
$$
Put $\lambda = \dfrac{n}{x}, \alpha = n$ to get
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{\Gamma(n)}\exp(-n\dfrac{u}{x}) u^{n-1}du = \left(\dfrac{x}{n}\right)^n
$$

So $$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n \ge 1}\left( \dfrac{x}{n} \right)^n &=  \int_{0}^{\infty}\exp(-\dfrac{u}{x}) \sum_{n \geq 1} \dfrac{\left(u \exp(-\dfrac{u}{x})\right)^{n-1}}{\Gamma(n)} du\\  &= \int_{0}^{\infty} \exp\left(-\dfrac{u}{x} + u\exp(-\dfrac{u}{x})\right)du.
\end{align}
$$

Substituting $u = -x \log t$ in the above integral we have $$\sum_{n \ge 1}\left( \dfrac{x}{n} \right)^n = \int_{0}^{1} \exp(\log t  -x t\log t) x \dfrac{dt}{t} = x\int_{0}^{1} \dfrac{1}{t^{tx}}dt. $$

A proof for $\eqref{e:2}$.

Let $M = \sup_{x \in [0,1]} g(x) > 0.$ Clearly $\left(\int_{0}^{1} (g(t))^{x}\right)^{1/x} \leq (M^x)^{1/x} = M.$ There is a $x_0 \in [0,1]$ such that $M = g(x_0)$, and for any $ \epsilon > 0$ we have a $\delta > 0 $ such that $|x - x_0| \leq  \delta$ and $0 \leq x \leq 1$ implies $ g(x) \geq M - \epsilon$ and 
$$
\left(\int_{0}^{1} (g(t))^{x}\right)^{1/x} \geq  \left(\int_{|x - x_0| < \delta} (g(t))^{x}\right)^{1/x} \geq (M-\epsilon) \ell^{1/x}
$$
where $\ell$ is the length of the interval where $0 \leq x \leq 1$ and $ |x - x_0| \leq \delta.$ Since $\ell^{1/x} \to 1$ as $x \to \infty$ the result follows.