# On the behaviour of $\left(1+\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^{n+1}-\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I have to find the limit : (let $k\in \mathbb{R}$)

> $$\lim_{n\to \infty}n^k \left(\Big(1+\frac{1}{n+1}\Big)^{n+1}-\Big(1+\frac{1}{n}\Big)^n \right)=?$$

My Try :

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{n^k}{\Big(1+\frac{1}{n}\Big)^n} \left(\frac{\Big(1+\frac{1}{n+1}\Big)^{n+1}}{\Big(1+\frac{1}{n}\Big)^n}-1\right)$$

we know that :

$$\frac{\Big(1+\frac{1}{n+1}\Big)^{n+1}}{\Big(1+\frac{1}{n}\Big)^n}>1$$

now what do i do ?

Answer (score 4):

$$\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n = \exp\left[n\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)\right]=e-\frac{e}{2n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right) $$
hence
$$ \left(1+\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^{n+1}-\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n = \frac{e}{2n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right) $$
and for a fixed $k\in\mathbb{R}$
$$ \lim_{n\to +\infty}n^k\left[\left(1+\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^{n+1}-\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n\right]$$
is non-trivial only if $k=2$. Otherwise, it is either $0$ or $+\infty$.

Comment: thank you very much . now  how without using  from big o notation ?

Comment: @Fricul38: you may prove the same through the AM-GM inequality and squeezing, but it is an overcomplication from my point of view. What is your issue with Landau's notation? It is very practical.

Comment: I prove with AM-GM that :
$$n^k \left((1+\frac{1}{n+1})^{n+1}-(1+\frac{1}{n})^n \right)>0$$
Now what ?

Comment: @Fricul38: you need to prove a non-trivial inequality, of course. It is well known that $\{(1+1/n)^n\}_{n\geq 1}$ is increasing, through the AM-GM or not. You need tight bounds for $$\frac{\left(1+\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^{n+1}}{\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n}-1=\left(1+\frac{1}{n+1}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}\right)^n-1,$$ but again, such detour is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}n^k \left((1+\frac{1}{n+1})^{n+1}-(1+\frac{1}{n})^n \right)=
\lim_{n\to \infty}n^k \left(\frac{e}{2n^2}+O((\frac{1}{n^3})) \right)$$
for n<2 limit is 0, for n=2 limit is e/2, for n>2 limit is infinity

Comment: You should see the other answer which explains how the equation is obtained. Just stating a complicated result is only going to confuse the asker.

Answer (score 1):

Using only the Binomial Theorem and Bernoulli's Inequality:
$$
\begin{align}
\hspace{-1cm}\left(1+\frac1{n+1}\right)^{n+1}\!\!-\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n
&=\left(\frac{n+2}{n+1}\right)^{n+1}-\left(\frac{n+1}n\right)^n\tag{1a}\\
&=\color{#C00}{\left(\frac{n+1}n-\frac1{(n+1)n}\right)^{n+1}}-\color{#090}{\left(\frac{n+1}n\right)^n}\tag{1b}\\
&=\color{#C00}{\left(\frac{n+1}n\right)^{n+1}-(n+1)\left(\frac{n+1}n\right)^n\frac1{(n+1)n}}\\
&\color{#C00}{{}+\frac{(n+1)n}2\left(\frac{n+1}n\right)^{n-1}\left(\frac1{(n+1)n}\right)^2+O\!\left(\frac1{n^3}\right)}\\
&-\color{#090}{\left(\frac{n+1}n\right)^n}\tag{1c}\\
&=\frac{(n+1)n}2\left(\frac{n+1}n\right)^{n-1}\left(\frac1{(n+1)n}\right)^2+O\!\left(\frac1{n^3}\right)\tag{1d}\\
&=\frac1{2(n+1)n}\left(\frac{n+1}n\right)^{n-1}+O\!\left(\frac1{n^3}\right)\tag{1e}\\[3pt]
&=\frac{e}{2n^2}+O\!\left(\frac1{n^3}\right)\tag{1f}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(1a)}$: combine terms
$\text{(1b)}$: add and subtract $\frac1{(n+1)n}$
$\text{(1c)}$: expand the first three terms of the Binomial expansion
$\text{(1d)}$: the sum of the first two terms of the Binomial expansion
$\phantom{\text{(1d):}}$ equals $\left(\frac{n+1}n\right)^n$
$\text{(1e)}$: simplify
$\text{(1f)}$: $\frac1{(n+1)n}=\frac1{n^2}+O\!\left(\frac1{n^3}\right)$  and $\left(\frac{n+1}n\right)^{n-1}=e+O\!\left(\frac1n\right)$
$\phantom{\text{(1f):}}$ the latter equation uses [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/306245) to show that
$\phantom{\text{(1f):}}$ $\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n\le e\le\left(1+\frac1n\right)^{n+1}$ with Bernoulli's Inequality