# Is the sequence $a_n=(1 + n^{-1/2})^\sqrt n$ bounded and monotone?

Tags: sequences-and-series

It's clear that $a_n=(1 + n^{-1/2})^\sqrt n =(1+ \frac{1}{\sqrt n})^\sqrt n $, which seems to be pretty similar to, $ (1+ \frac{1}{n}) ^n$ but how can I continue to solve this problem?

Comment: the Limit is also $e$

Comment: To be totally correct, one really needs to show that $\left(1+\frac1x\right)^x$ is increasing for real $x\gt0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$n\longmapsto \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n$ and $n\longmapsto \sqrt n$ are increasing. Therefore, $(a_n)$ is a composition of two increasing functions, and thus, it's also increasing.

Comment: Surb.Please elaborate . (1+1/n)^n is increasing, is that so obvious?Thanks, Peter

Comment: @PeterSzilas : I let you manage this ;-) First, it's not hard and very famous ! secondly, if you search a little bit, I'm sure you can find such a result on MSE... The idea is to use binomial theorem...

Comment: @Surb: this leaves me uncomfortable since most of the proofs using the binomial theorem, or Bernoulli's inequality for that matter, work only for integer $n$. Composing with $\sqrt{n}$ takes us out of that realm.

Comment: @robjohn: for $(1+\frac{1}{n})^n$ using binomial theorem is great (of course I don't use it on $a_n$). For the composition function, I use the general fact that if $f:(X,\leq_1)\to (Y,\leq _2)$ and $g:(Y,\leq_2)\to (Z,\leq_3)$ are increasing, then $g\circ f:(X,\leq_1)\to (Z,\leq_3)$ is increasing...

Comment: @Surb: but what version of the Binomial Theorem are you using to prove that $\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n$ is increasing? Does it only show that $\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n\le\left(1+\frac1{n+1}\right)^{n+1}$? If so, then that is not really good enough since $\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}=\frac1{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}\lt1$.

Comment: @robjohn : yes it's to show $(1+\frac{1}{n})^n\leq (1+\frac{1}{n+1})^{n+1}$. I don't understand your counter example, sorry.

Comment: Surb.ok, thanks for your reply.:)

Comment: @Surb: This approach shows that for $n\in\mathbb{Z}^+$, $\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n$ is increasing. However, it doesn't show what happens between integers and to compose with $\sqrt{n}$, which are not all in $\mathbb{Z}$, we should show that $\left(1+\frac1x\right)^x$ is increasing for real $x\gt0$. It is only your comment regarding the Binomial Theorem that I am questioning, not your answer, which does not refer to the Binomial Theorem.

Answer (score 2):

I was going to cite [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/306245) to show that $\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n$ was increasing. Then I realized that that answer only showed this increase for integer $n$, so composing with $\sqrt{n}$ would not really work. Thus, I feel this increase needs to be shown for real $n$.

---

For $u\gt-1$,
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}u}\left(u-\log(1+u)\right)
=\frac{u}{1+u}\\
$$
which means that for $-1\lt u\lt0$, $u-\log(1+u)$ is decreasing, and for $u\gt0$, $u-\log(1+u)$ is increasing. Thus, $u-\log(1+u)$ has a minimum at $u=0$. That is, for $u\gt-1$,
$$
u-\log(1+u)\ge0
$$

---

For $x\gt0$, we have $u=-\frac1{1+x}\gt-1$, and therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\,x\log\left(1+\frac1x\right)
&=\overbrace{-\frac1{1+x}\ \ }^u-\overbrace{\log\left(1-\frac1{1+x}\right)}^{\log(1+u)}\\
&\ge0
\end{align}
$$

---

This means that for $x\gt0$, $\left(1+\frac1x\right)^x$ is increasing since its logarithm is increasing.

Now we can set $x=\sqrt{n}$ and get that the composition of increasing functions
$$
\left(1+\frac1{\sqrt{n}}\right)^{\large\sqrt{n}}
$$
is increasing.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the function $$ f(x)=(1+1/x)^x$$

Note that $f(x)$ is monotone and bounded over $[1,\infty).$

Thus $$ a_n=(1+ \frac{1}{\sqrt n})^\sqrt n$$ is monotone and bounded.