# Is it true that $2\frac{(2n+1)^{2n+1}}{(2n+2)^{2n+2}} \le \frac{n^n}{(n+1)^{n+1}} \le 2\frac{(2n)^{2n}}{(2n+1)^{2n+1}}$

Tags: inequality

I conjectured the following for positive integers $n$

$$2\frac{(2n+1)^{2n+1}}{(2n+2)^{2n+2}} \le \frac{n^n}{(n+1)^{n+1}} \le 2\frac{(2n)^{2n}}{(2n+1)^{2n+1}}$$

It seems to be true for the (few) values I have tried and I was wondering if it is true for all $n \in \mathbb N_{>0}$? If so how might I see this?

Comment: How about by induction?  How many values (and which values) have you tested?

Comment: I tried $n=1$ and $n=24$. I tried induction but the induction step doesn't come out

Comment: The first test:  Plot them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prove
$$
2\frac{(2n+1)^{2n+1}}{(2n+2)^{2n+2}}\le\frac{n^n}{(n+1)^{n+1}}\le2\frac{(2n)^{2n}}{(2n+1)^{2n+1}}
$$
note that the left-hand inequality is equivalent to
$$
\left(1+\frac1{2n+1}\right)^{2n+1}\ge\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n
$$
which follows from the monotonic increase of $\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n$ proven in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/306245) using only [Bernoulli's Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality).

The right-hand inequality is equivalent to
$$
\left(1+\frac1n\right)^{n+1}\ge\left(1+\frac1{2n}\right)^{2n+1}
$$
which follows from the monotonic decrease of $\left(1+\frac1n\right)^{n+1}$ proven in [the same answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/306245), again  using only [Bernoulli's Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality).

Answer (score 0):

The function
\begin{eqnarray*}
\left( 1+ \frac{1}{x} \right)^x
\end{eqnarray*}
is increasing so
\begin{eqnarray*}
\left( 1+ \frac{1}{2n} \right)^{2n} \leq \left( 1+ \frac{1}{2n+1} \right)^{2n+1} \leq \left( 1+ \frac{1}{2n+1} \right)^{2n+2}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Square root this to get
\begin{eqnarray*}
\left( 1+ \frac{1}{2n} \right)^{n} \leq  \left( 1+ \frac{1}{2n+1} \right)^{n+1}.
\end{eqnarray*}
This can be rearranged to give the upper bound ...
\begin{eqnarray*}
n \ln(1+\frac{1}{2n}) \leq (n+1) \ln (1+\frac{1}{2n+1}) \\
\end{eqnarray*}
\begin{eqnarray*}
n( \ln(n+\frac{1}{2}) -\ln(n)) \leq (n+1) (\ln(n+1)- \ln(n+\frac{1}{2})) \\
\end{eqnarray*}
\begin{eqnarray*}(2n+1) \ln(n+\frac{1}{2}) \leq n \ln (n) +(n+1) \ln(n+1) \\
\end{eqnarray*}
\begin{eqnarray*}n \ln n +(2n+1) \ln(2n+1) \leq \ln 2 +2n \ln(2n) +(n+1) \ln(n+1) \\
\end{eqnarray*}
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{n^n}{(n+1)^{n+1}} \leq 2 \frac{(2n)^{2n}}{(2n+1)^{2n+1}}.
\end{eqnarray*}
The lower bound can probably be shown similarly.

Answer (score 0):

At least, for large values of $n$, take the logarithms and expand as series to get
$$\log\left(2\frac{(2n+1)^{2n+1}}{(2n+2)^{2n+2}}\right)=-\log \left({n}\right)-1-\frac{3}{4 n}+\frac{7}{24
   n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$ 
$$\log\left(\frac{n^n}{(n+1)^{n+1}}\right)=-\log \left({n}\right)-1-\frac{1}{2 n}+\frac{1}{6
   n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$
$$\log\left(2\frac{(2n)^{2n}}{(2n+1)^{2n+1}}\right)=-\log \left({n}\right)-1-\frac{1}{4 n}+\frac{1}{24
   n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$ Now, using $A=e^{\log(A)}$, we have, for large $n$,
$$2\frac{(2n+1)^{2n+1}}{(2n+2)^{2n+2}}=\frac 1e \left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{3}{4 n^2}+\frac{55}{96
   n^3}\right)+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)$$
$$\frac{n^n}{(n+1)^{n+1}}=\frac 1e \left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{2 n^2}+\frac{7}{24
   n^3}\right)+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)$$
$$2\frac{(2n)^{2n}}{(2n+1)^{2n+1}}=\frac 1e \left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{4 n^2}+\frac{7}{96
   n^3}\right)+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)$$ Now, you can conclude since 
$$\frac{n^n}{(n+1)^{n+1}}-2\frac{(2n+1)^{2n+1}}{(2n+2)^{2n+2}}=\frac{1}{4 e n^2}-\frac{9}{32 e n^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)$$
$$2\frac{(2n)^{2n}}{(2n+1)^{2n+1}}-\frac{n^n}{(n+1)^{n+1}}=\frac{1}{4 e n^2}-\frac{7}{32 e n^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)$$