# Prove $\left(1-\frac{1}{n^2}\right)^n\times\left(1+\frac 1n\right)<1$ for every natural $n > 0$ by induction

Tags: inequality, induction, natural-numbers

Consider this inequality

$$\left(1-\dfrac{1}{n^2}\right)^n\times\left(1+\dfrac 1n\right)<1$$ 
which is meant to be **valid** for any nonzero natural number $n$.

It is asked to prove it **by induction**. I haven't made any significant progress after many tries.

Any advice is welcome.

**Note :**

A way I encountered which looks nicer and more straightforward is to notice that 
$1-\dfrac{1}{n^2}<1-\dfrac{1}{n^2+k}$ for $k\in \{1,\cdots,n\}$

Multiplying side by side those $n$ inequalities, a nice telescoping takes place to give exaclty the sought result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Applying [Bernoulli's Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality) to the reciprocal, we get
$$
\begin{align}
\left(1+\frac1{n^2-1}\right)^n\left(1-\frac1{n+1}\right)
&\ge\left(1+\frac{n}{n^2-1}\right)\left(1-\frac1{n+1}\right)\\
&=\frac{n^3+n^2-n}{n^3+n^2-n-1}
\end{align}
$$
Therefore, we get
$$
\left(1-\frac1{n^2}\right)^n\left(1+\frac1n\right)
\le1-\frac1{n^3+n^2-n}
$$

Answer (score 2):

Actually, to prove $$\left(1-\dfrac{1}{n^2}\right)^n\times\left(1+\dfrac 1n\right)=\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^n\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{1+n}<1$$
It suffices to prove $$\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{1+n}\le \left(1+\frac{1}{1-n}\right)^n$$
which is obvious since $\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{1+n} $ is a decreasing sequence.

Comment: (+1) It may not be obvious to everyone that $\left(1+\frac1n\right)^{n+1}$ is decreasing. Citing [a proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/306245/13854) might be useful. ;-)

Comment: Guo. Last line. RHS, should be (1+1/(n-1))^n?

Answer (score 2):

The inequality 
$\left(1-\dfrac{1}{n^2}\right)^n\cdot\left(1+\dfrac 1n\right)
=\left(1-\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^n\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^{n+1}
=\dfrac{\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^{n+1}}{\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n-1}\right)^{n}}<1$
is equivalent to the sequence 
$\left\{\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^{n+1}\right\}$
is strictly decreasing.

So we will show that：sequence 
$\left\{\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^{n+1}\right\}$
is strictly decreasing.
By AG-MG inequality
$\dfrac{1}{\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^{n+1}}=\left(\dfrac{n}{n+1}\right)^{n+1}
=1\cdot\dfrac{n}{n+1}\cdot\dfrac{n}{n+1}\cdots\dfrac{n}{n+1}
<\left(\dfrac{n+1}{n+2}\right)^{n+2}$
$=\left(\dfrac{n+1}{n+2}\right)^{n+2}=\dfrac{1}{\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n+1}\right)^{n+2}}.$

Hence $$\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^{n+1}>\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n+1}\right)^{n+2}.$$

Comment: (+1) this is a fleshing out of the idea in J.Guo's answer.

Comment: @robjohn   It is well know that the sequence $\left\{\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^{n}\right\}$ is strictly increasing tending to $e$ and the sequence $ \left\{\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^{n+1}\right\}$  is strictly decreasing tending to $e$ in the standard Calculus textbook.

Comment: "well-known" is a relative term. If these are well-known to everyone who reads this answer, then this answer provides nothing more than J.Guo's answer and my upvote was misplaced. However, I think the AM-GM proof here may be new to some readers and, therefore, is worth the upvote.

Comment: Thank you for your comment !