# Does the nth root of $n \cdot 2^{3n}+3^{2n}$ converge as $n \to \infty$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, exponential-function, radicals

Consider the sequence

> $a_n = \sqrt[n]{n \cdot 2^{3n}+3^{2n}}$, $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

With a string of inequalities, one can show that $a_n$ is bounded and the graph of the function $ f(x) = \sqrt[x]{x \cdot 2^{3x}+3^{2x}}$ suggests that $f$ is monotone, but how could one prove convergence and a calculate the limit of $a_n$?

I would be grateful for any help!

Comment: Hint. $a_n = 9\sqrt[n]{n \cdot (8/9)^n+1}$

Comment: Adapt [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3004091).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite as $\lim 8\sqrt[n]{1+(9/8)^n}\ge \lim 8\sqrt[n]{(9/8)^n}=9$ and $$\lim 8\sqrt[n]{n+(9/8)^n}\le \lim 8\sqrt[n]{2(9/8)^n}=9.$$ So the limit is $9$.

Comment: It is $\sqrt[n]{n+(9/8)^n}$ instead of $\sqrt[n]{1+(9/8)^n}$.

Comment: Yes, it does not matter because $(9/8)^n\le n+(9/8)^n\le 2(9/8)^n$ for large enough $n$. I have fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $$a_n = \sqrt[n]{n\cdot 8^n+9^n} = 9\cdot \sqrt[n]{n\cdot \left(\frac{8}{9}\right)^n+1}$$
Denote by $ \displaystyle b_n = n\cdot \left(\frac{8}{9}\right)^n$. Since
$$\frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n} = \frac{n+1}{n}\cdot \frac{8}{9} \longrightarrow \frac{8}{9}<1$$
it follows that $b_n \longrightarrow0$, and thus $a_n \longrightarrow 9$.

Addendum: Since $1\le b_n+1$ it follows that $1\le \sqrt[n]{b_n+1}\le b_n+1$. Thus, by the squeezing principle, $\sqrt[n]{b_n+1}$ tends to $1$, as I claimed.

Comment: $\lim 1/2^n=0$ but $\lim \sqrt[n]{1/2^n}=1/2$

Comment: How about lim $\sqrt[n]{1/2^n+1}$?

Comment: It is $1$. What about it?

Comment: I don't get the idea of your first comment. I thought you are trying to point out a mistake in my argument.

Comment: Your argument is wrong because from $a_n\to a$ does not follow that $\sqrt[n]{a_n}\to 1$. You claim without a proof that since $b_n+1\to 1$ then $\sqrt[n]{b_n+1}=1$.

Comment: Please read my proof carefully. What I use in the proof is the following: If a sequence $x_n$ tends to $0$, then $\sqrt[n]{x_n+1}$ tends to $1$.

Comment: As I said, you did not prove this fact. It is wrong if we replace the first $1$ by $0$.