# Does this sequence converge? Alternating and exponential

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(-1\right)^k\frac{\left(k+1\right)^{k+1}}{k^{k+2}}$$

I started to use Dirichlet's test. However, the latter half does not decrease to 0. I am unsure of what to do.

Comment: Hint: divide the numerator and the denominator by $k^{k+1}$.

Comment: This is NOT a [Dirichlet series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_series). Please don't pick tags randomly.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Consider
$$a_k=\frac{(k+1)^{k+1}}{k^{k+2}}\implies \log(a_k)=(k+1)\log(k+1)-(k+2)\log(k)$$
Now, make $\log(a_{k+1})-\log({a_k})$ and use Taylor expansions for large values of $k$. This should give
$$\log(a_{k+1})-\log({a_k})=-\frac{1}{k}+O\left(\frac{1}{k^2}\right)$$ $$\frac{a_{k+1} } {{a_k} }= e^{\log(a_{k+1})-\log({a_k})}=1-\frac{1}{k}+O\left(\frac{1}{k^2}\right)$$ and you face an alternating series.

Answer (score 0):

You can see that it is an alternating series $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(-1)^k a_k$ with $a_k \searrow 0$ using the following fact:

- $(1+\frac{1}{k})^{k+1}$ is decreasing ([proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/306178/given-y-n-1-frac1nn1-show-that-lbrace-y-n-rbrace-is-a-decreasin)) with its know limit $e$.

Hence, you get

$$a_k = \frac{\left(k+1\right)^{k+1}}{k^{k+2}} =\frac{1}{k}\left(\frac{k+1}{k}\right)^{k+1}= \frac{1}{k}\underbrace{\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)^{k+1}}_{\searrow\; e} \Rightarrow a_k \searrow \; 0$$

So, you conclude the convergence of your series using the alternating series test.