# compare $m=50^{50}$ with $n=49^{51}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, exponentiation

A multiple choice question:

> If $m=50^{50}$ and $n=49^{51}$, then
>
> (A) $m>n$
>
> (B) $m<n$
>
> (C) $m=n$
>
> (D) The given information is not enough

### My attempt:

Since ordinary calculators can not evaluate large numbers as $m$ and $n$, then we can use a trick, which is taking the logarithm of both $m$ and $n$ to the same base, lets use $\ln$ (log to the base $e$).

$50\ln(50)$ VS $51\ln(49)$

$195.60$ VS $198.48$

Hence $49^{51}$ is greater.

So, B must be the correct choice.

---

This question was asked in a national exam for high school students.

---

### However:

- Calculators are not allowed.
- Log tables are not provided.
- Students may not have any knowledge about logarithms and their properties.
- Students should have basic knowledge about exponents like $(a/b)^k=a^k/b^k$, $a^j \times a^k = a^{(j+k)}$, and some other basics.
- The average time to solve a question in this exam is 75 seconds.

---

How can we answer this question?

Answer (score 16):

Hint: Use the inequality $$\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)^x>\frac{1}{x-1}$$

Comment: From where did you come with this equality? How can we derive it? It holds true for $x<0$ or $x>4.14...$.

Comment: @Hussain-Alqatari We only need it for large enough positive $x$, since the left-hand side increases while the right-hand side decreases. For $x>5$, $\left(1-1/x\right)^x>0.32768$ while $1/(x-1)<0.25$.

Comment: Lets say $$x=50$$ so we have to show that $$(x-1)^{x+1}>x^x$$ this is the inequality above.

Answer (score 10):

We have $$\frac{n}{m} = \frac{49^{51}}{50^{50}} = 49 \cdot \left(\frac{49}{50}\right)^{50} = 49 \cdot \left(1-\frac{1}{50}\right)^{50} \approx \frac{49}{e} > 1$$
Even if you dont know that for large $n$ $$ \left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n} \approx \frac{1}{e}$$
as long as you're able to tell that $$\left(1-\frac{1}{50}\right)^{50} > \frac{1}{49}$$ you're fine. You can get that for example from Bernoulli's inequality. For $x>-1$:
$$ (1+x)^n \ge 1+xn$$
so
$$ \left(1-\frac{1}{50}\right)^{50} = \left(\left(1-\frac{1}{50}\right)^{25} \right)^2 \ge \left(1-\frac{1}{50}\cdot 25\right)^2 = \left(\frac12\right)^2 = \frac14 > \frac{1}{49}$$

Answer (score 5):

Use [Bernoulli's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli's_inequality) with $x=-\frac{1}{50}$ and $r=48$:

$$\frac{49^{51}}{50^{50}}=\frac{49^3}{50^2}\cdot\frac{49^{48}}{50^{48}}=\frac{49^3}{50^2}\left(1-\frac{1}{50}\right)^{48}\ge\frac{49^3}{50^2}\left(1-\frac{48}{50}\right)=\frac{2\cdot49^3}{50^3}>1$$

Comment: One more application of Bernoulli to show that $\frac{2\cdot49^3}{50^3}\ge\frac{2\cdot47}{50}\gt1$ might help those who can't compute $49^3$ in their heads (although $50^3$ is quite possible).

Answer (score 4):

In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/306245), it is shown that $\left(1+\frac1{n-1}\right)^n$ is decreasing. That means that its reciprocal $\left(1-\frac1n\right)^n$ is increasing. Thus, for $n\ge2$, we have
$$
\left(1-\frac1n\right)^n\ge\frac14\tag1
$$
Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{49^{51}}{50^{50}}
&=49\left(1-\frac1{50}\right)^{50}\\
&\ge\frac{49}4\tag2
\end{align}
$$

---

**Another Proof of $\boldsymbol{(1)}$**

Using Theorem $1$ from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3259176) with $m=2$, we get
$$
\begin{align}
\left(1-\frac1n\right)^n
&\ge1-\frac{n}{n}+\frac{n(n-1)}{2n^2}-\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{6n^3}\\
&=\frac{n^2-1}{3n^2}\tag3
\end{align}
$$
For $n\ge2$, $(3)$ gives $(1)$.

Answer (score 0):

Knowing the following fairly common limit is very useful:

$$ \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{x} \right)^x=e \approx 3$$

$$50^{50}<49^{51}$$
$$\left(\frac{50}{49}\right)^{50}<49$$
$$\left(1+\frac{1}{49}\right)^{50}<49$$
$$\left(1+\frac{1}{49}\right)^{50} \approx e \approx 3$$
$$3<49$$
Therefore we conclude that $50^{50}<49^{51}$

Answer (score -1):

Note that $(1+x)^n=1+nx+\frac{n(n-1)}{2}x^2+\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{6}x^3+\dots+x^n$

$50^{50}$ and $49^{51}$

$50^{50}$ and $49^{50}\cdot49$

$(\frac{50}{49})^{50}$ and $49$

$(1+\frac{1}{49})^{50}$ and $49$

$1+50(\frac{1}{49})+\underset{\text{Negligible terms}}{\underbrace{\frac{50\times49}{2}(\frac{1}{49})^2+\frac{50\times49\times48}{6}(\frac{1}{49})^3+\dots+(\frac{1}{49})^{50}}}$ and $49$

$1+\frac{50}{49}$ and $49$

Clearly, $1+\frac{50}{49}<49$. Hence $50^{50}<49^{51}$. Thus, B is the correct choice.

Answer (score -1):

Why do you just compute the two numbers?
The following code is in Julia.

```
m = BigInt(50)^50
n = BigInt(49)^51
sign(m-n)
```

The output is `-1` which means $m-n < 0$.

Comment: While this settles the question of which is larger, the OP expressly indicates that the problem is in the context of a national exam where calculators are unavailable. So the question is not "which is larger" but rather how to determine this by pencil-and-paper.