# How to prove $(n+1/2)\log (1+1/n)-1 >0$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, complex-analysis, analysis

I want to show the following statement:

For any integer $n$ with $n\geq 1$,
$$\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right) \log \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right) -1>0.$$
or equivalently, $$\log \left(n+1\right)-\log \left(n\right) >\frac{2}{2n+1 }.
$$
Here log represents the natural log function.
I am able to prove $$\log \left(n+1\right)-\log \left(n\right) >\frac{1}{n+1 }.
$$ but not much luck with getting $\frac{2}{2n+1 }$. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: use that the derivative of $f(x)=\log (x+1)-\log x-\frac{2}{2x+1}$ is negative (it is $-1/(x(x+1)(2x+1)^2)$) on $[1, \infty)$ hence $f$ is decreasing and $\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x)=0$

Comment: I believe I can prove that f  is decreasing but how do you know that the limit of f is zero?

Comment: $f(x)=\log (1+1/x)-\frac{2}{2x+1}$ and each term goes to zero

Comment: Oh, yea! That's perfect. Thanks a lot!

Comment: happy to be of help

Comment: Related $\;-\;$ [Is $\left(1+\frac1n\right)^{n+1/2}$ decreasing?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3259175/is-left1-frac1n-rightn1-2-decreasing)

Comment: = =hahaha,when I finished editing, I saw your comments.

Answer (score 3):

For any integer $n$ with $n≥1$,$$\Big(n+\frac{1}{2}\Big)\log\Big(1+\frac{1}{n}\Big)-1>0$$
let $x=\frac{1}{n}$, then
$$\Big(n+\frac{1}{2}\Big)\log\Big(1+\frac{1}{n}\Big)-1>0,n\geq1$$
$$\Leftrightarrow (\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{2})\log(1+x)-1>0,1\geq x>0$$
$$\Leftrightarrow \log(1+x)>\frac{2x}{x+2},1\geq x>0$$
let$$F(x)=\log(1+x)-\frac{2x}{x+2}$$
then:$$F'(x)=\frac{1}{x+1}-\frac{2(x+2)-2x}{(x+2)^2}=\frac{(x+2)^2-4(x+1)}{(x+1)(x+2)^2}=\frac{x^2}{(x+1)(x+2)^2}>0$$
so $F(x)$ is monotonically increasing function.So $F(x)>F(0)=0$.Done.

Comment: sorry，is$F'(x)=\frac{1}{1+x}-\frac{2(x+2)-2x}{(x+2)^2}$

Comment: You can edit your answer to make correction, no need to make a comment about it. I fixed it for you this time.

Comment: haha ,thank you.I just used this editor, not familiar with it,

Comment: Just below the text of your answer there is a series of options: Share $\;$  Cite $\;$  Edit  $\;$ Delete  $\;$ Flag. Choose Edit and you can edit your answer. $\;$

Comment: hahaha……，I get it ,thank you thank you.