# Existence of limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n!}{n^{n+1/2}e^{-n}}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

It is shown that
$$
 e^{\frac{11}{12}}n^{n+1/2}e^{-n}< n!<en^{n+1/2}e^{-n}.
$$
The question is, how to conclude from here that the limit
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n!}{n^{n+1/2}e^{-n}}
$$
exists? I suspect that $\frac{n!}{n^{n+1/2}e^{-n}}$ is decreasing, but I can't prove this claim.

Note: I am studying a topic about [Stirling's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation), so please avoid mentioning that the limit exists due to that formula.

Comment: I remember the answer is in the book of E. Artin "the Gamma function". May be it's online

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can prove the monotonicity as follows. Let $a_n \mathop  = \limits^{\small{\rm def}} \frac{{n!}}{{n^{n + 1/2} \mathrm{e}^{ - n} }}$. Then
$$
\frac{{a_n }}{{a_{n + 1} }} = \left( {1 + \frac{1}{n}} \right)^{n + 1/2} \frac{1}{\mathrm{e}} = \exp \left( {\left( {n + \frac{1}{2}} \right)\log \left( {1 + \frac{1}{n}} \right) - 1} \right).
$$
But
\begin{align*}
\left( {n + \frac{1}{2}} \right)\log \left( {1 + \frac{1}{n}} \right) - 1 &= (2n + 1)\frac{1}{2}\log \left( {\frac{{1 + \frac{1}{{2n + 1}}}}{{1 - \frac{1}{{2n + 1}}}}} \right) - 1 \\ & = (2n + 1)\tanh ^{ - 1} \left( {\frac{1}{{2n + 1}}} \right) - 1,
\end{align*}
and $\tanh ^{ - 1} (x) = x + \frac{{x^3 }}{3} + \frac{{x^5 }}{5} +  \ldots  > x$ for $0<x<1$, i.e.,
$$
\left( {n + \frac{1}{2}} \right)\log \left( {1 + \frac{1}{n}} \right) - 1 > (2n + 1)\frac{1}{{2n + 1}} - 1 = 0.
$$
Consequently,
$$
\frac{{a_n }}{{a_{n + 1} }} > \mathrm{e}^0  = 1,
$$
i.e., the sequence $a_n$ is strictly decreasing.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the help. You really are a quick-thinker. Since $(a_n)$ is strictly decreasing and is bounded below by $e^{11/12}$, one can conclude that the limit of $(a_n)$ exists, right? And since it is bounded above by $e$, the limit lies between $e^{11/12}$ and $e$. Does it sound fine?

Comment: @Mr.MathDoctor Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 1):

$x\mapsto-\frac1{n-x}$ is concave for $x\lt n$. Apply Jensen's Inequality
$$
\begin{align}
\log\left(\frac{n-1}n\right)
&=-\int_0^1\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{n-x}\tag{1a}\\[3pt]
&\le-\frac1{n-\int_0^1x\,\mathrm{d}x}\tag{1b}\\
&=-\frac1{n-1/2}\tag{1c}
\end{align}
$$
which implies
$$
\left(\frac{n-1}n\right)^{n-1/2}\le\frac1e\tag2
$$
Thus,
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\frac{n!}{n^{n+1/2}e^{-n}}}{\frac{(n-1)!}{(n-1)^{n-1/2}e^{1-n}}}
&=e\left(\frac{n-1}n\right)^{n-1/2}\tag{3a}\\
&\le1\tag{3b}
\end{align}
$$
Therefore, $\frac{n!}{n^{n+1/2}e^{-n}}$ is decreasing.